# Is changing div's height after browser resize to size dependent on text's length and font's size an good idea?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, frontend

I had some troubles with handling div's size with huge walls of texts for mobiles

So, I came with an idea "what If there's an formula that basing on screen's width/height can set proper height to that div?"

And resulted in something hardcode-ish like:

https://jsfiddle.net/qmde87kt/ (Resize view window a few times)

```js
$(window).resize(function() {
  var div = document.getElementById("test");
  var width = div.offsetWidth;
  var height = (div.innerHTML.length * 70) / width;
  div.setAttribute("style", "height:" + height + "px");

});
```

```css
#test {
  font-size: 10px;
  border: 2px solid red;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="test">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis commodo massa iaculis, elementum dolor bibendum, maximus orci. Aliquam imperdiet metus mi. Vestibulum cursus elementum ex in tempus. Nulla accumsan, ex eget rhoncus mollis, lectus lacus sodales
  neque, ut dictum nibh elit eget tellus. Vestibulum tincidunt quis mi quis egestas. Aenean ultricies purus nunc, id facilisis ante eleifend sed. Proin rutrum luctus turpis, sed pellentesque lorem consequat a. Quisque tortor leo, tempus in ante ac, mattis
  faucibus risus. Praesent tristique, odio ac finibus tristique, neque sapien aliquet dolor, in finibus mauris urna sit amet mauris. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Praesent nunc est, fringilla in condimentum et, gravida a ligula. Vivamus hendrerit
  mauris a venenatis dictum. Sed vitae mi eget diam dapibus ultricies. Suspendisse varius turpis ante, nec cursus felis luctus et. Etiam ac ligula et tellus viverra tristique sed sodales ex. Nullam accumsan volutpat libero, vel laoreet sem lacinia sit
  amet. Nam id mollis justo.
</div>
```

So, is there an way better (more universal) formula for something like this? or maybe there's an easier way to do that?

Comment: haha, sorry bud, this has been thought of! It's why your screen looks so good on mobile and everything seems to seamlessly resize. Look up CSS Media Queries, CSS Grid, and Flexbox

Comment: Or dynamic styles . . .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per what Rory suggestion, I would recommend media queries with below-suggested breakpoints

Min-width: 320px (smaller phone viewpoints)
Min-width: 480px (small devices and most phones)
Min-width: 768px (most tablets)
Min-width: 992px (smaller desktop viewpoints)
Min-width: 1200px (large devices and wide screens)

Setting with JS is anyway a costly JOB!!!

Comment: So, I have to hard code it? for phone devices height's is: X, for tablets, Y, for desktops Q?